# Flash Render Stop In Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, actionscript-3, flash

When switching to other website and then switch to our flash game after about ten 
minutes, the game occasionally stopped render, but the mouse click event can be captured(the flash do not update, but when it start to render, I know the mouse click event is captured).

If I resize the flash or switch to other software then switch back to chrome, the flash game will render normally.

The wmode is direct, and this is our [game](http://www.vnwebgame.com/flsg/?server=S339).

Comment: If resize does the trick, just force the resize handler on **Event.ACTIVATE** from **stage**.

Comment: @Organis Thank you. I will try it.

Comment: Sounds like the Android Black Screen bug. There are ANE helpers for this if you want to look into that path: https://distriqt.github.io/ANE-Application/u.General%20Helpers